# TabController.animateTo not being called in ref.listen of Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, state-management, riverpod

I created a StateProvider:

```
final tabsStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TabsProvider, List<TabClass>>(
    (ref) => TabsProvider());
```

and I'm listening to it with `ref.listen`:

Inside `ref.listen`, when the state changes, I'm calling `tabController.animateTo(1);` but it's not having any effect on the tabs. I'm not sure why.
I added a print statement in the `ref.listen` which gets called but `tabController.animateTo(1);` in particular is not getting called for some reason.

My class code:

```
class HomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends ConsumerState<HomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<TabClass> tabClassList = ref.watch(tabsStateProvider);
    TabsProvider tabsProvider = ref.watch(tabsStateProvider.notifier);
    tabController =
        TabController(length: ref.watch(tabsStateProvider).length, vsync: this);

    ref.listen(tabsStateProvider, (previousState, latestState) {
      debugPrint('TAB STATE -> $latestState');
      tabController.animateTo(1);
    });

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: DottedBorder(
            color: Colors.black,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            dashPattern: const [5, 5],
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    'Create',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: DefaultTabController(
            length: tabClassList.length,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                  child: AppBar(
                    bottom: TabBar(
                      controller: tabController,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      tabs: List.generate(
                        tabClassList.length,
                        (index) {
                          TabClass tabClass = tabClassList[index];
                          return Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              TitleWidget(title: tabClass.tabsTitle),
                              index != 0
                                  ? InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        tabsProvider.decrement(index);
                                      },
                                      child:
                                          Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red),
                                    )
                                  : SizedBox.shrink(),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                      controller: tabController,
                      children:
                          tabClassList.map((e) => e.tabBarViewWidget).toList()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I expected the tab to animate to the second tab which is position 1.

This is my state class:

```
final tabsStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TabsProvider, List<TabClass>>(
    (ref) => TabsProvider());

class TabsProvider extends StateNotifier<List<TabClass>> {
  TabsProvider()
      : super([
          TabClass(tabsTitle: 'Tab 1', tabBarViewWidget: TabBarViewWidget())
        ]);

  void increment() => state = [
        ...state,
        TabClass(
            tabsTitle: 'Tab ${state.length + 1}',
            tabBarViewWidget: TabBarViewWidget())
      ];

  void decrement(int index) => state = [
        for (final tab in state)
          if (tab.tabsTitle != state[index].tabsTitle) tab
      ];
}

class TabClass {
  final String tabsTitle;
  final TabBarViewWidget tabBarViewWidget;

  TabClass({required this.tabsTitle, required this.tabBarViewWidget});
}
```

Comment: whan I add constant value    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this); It works .

Comment: Does ref.watch(tabsStateProvider).length return an Integer values ? Check it . Or , simply get length of. tabClassList.legth() .

Comment: I can't use a constant value because the length property of TabController is supposed to change as the user clicks on the FAB to add new tabs.

Yes, ref.watch(tabsStateProvider).length returns an Integer value.

Comment: I have checked your code and its working fine if I put constant values of lenth in Tabcontroller . May be ref.listen is not listing  .. (Not working) .     tabController.animateTo(1); is working fine in your code . I had run your code .

Comment: @RahulKushwaha like I mentioned, I don't want to have constant values in the TabController because the length property of TabController is supposed to change as the user clicks on the FAB to add new tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TabClass` objects must be immutable and have all `final` fields. Moreover, your `List<TabClass>` must be modified using the `List.of(...)` or `state = [...state]` method to change your state in `TabsProvider`.

Comment: Yes they are immutable and I'm using state = [...state].
I have updated my question by adding my state class. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

**tabController.animateTo(1)** : ***This is calling but widget is not updating*** . There is difference between ***ref.watch*** and ***ref.listen***. Due to this the controller's tab is not changing its positions .

****ref.listen****:-

The main difference between them is that, rather than rebuilding the widget/provider if the listened to provider changes, using ref.listen will instead call a custom function.

That can be useful for performing actions when a certain change happens, such as showing a snackbar when an error happens.

The ref.listen method needs 2 positional arguments, the first one is the Provider and the second one is the callback function that we want to execute when the state changes. The callback function when called will be passed 2 values, the value of the previous State and the value of the new State.

The ref.listen method can be used inside the body of a provider.
It is better to use for showing error message, Navigation,print , Scaffold etc.

**Check this link for preference** .
[ref.listen()](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-reflisten-to-react-to-a-provider-change)  and [ref.listen](https://github.com/bizz84/flutter-tips-and-tricks/blob/main/tips/0046-riverpod-difference-between-ref-watch-ref-read-ref-listen/index.md).

**I have updated your code and it's working now.**

```
class HomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends ConsumerState<HomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabClassList = ref.watch(tabsStateProvider);

    tabController = TabController(length: tabClassList.length, vsync: this);

    tabController.animateTo(tabClassList.length - 1);
    ref.listen(tabsStateProvider,
        (List<TabClass> previousState, List<TabClass> latestState) {
      print('sdfsd');


        });

    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: DefaultTabController(
            length: tabClassList.length,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: AppBar(
                    leading: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          ref.read(tabsStateProvider.notifier).increment();
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.add)),
                    bottom: TabBar(
                      controller: tabController,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      tabs: List.generate(
                        tabClassList.length,
                        (index) {
                          TabClass tabClass = tabClassList[index];
                          return Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Text(tabClass.tabsTitle),
                              index != 0
                                  ? InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        ref
                                            .read(tabsStateProvider.notifier)
                                            .decrement(index);
                                      },
                                      child:
                                          Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red),
                                    )
                                  : SizedBox.shrink(),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                      controller: tabController,
                      children:
                          tabClassList.map((e) => e.tabBarViewWidget).toList()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

But it seems this will call animateTo() anytime the build method is called, I don't think that is what we want.